# Projecting a function onto a circle and unwrapping the circle

Tags: trigonometry, spherical-trigonometry

I have a blue curve, a simple circle $x^2+y^2=1$, onto which I am projecting, like a shadow, an exact function $F$. Let's say it's a simple Gaussian $F(x)=e^{-x^2}$ visualized in red below.

As the function is projected onto the shape, it ***does not wrap around it, but so-to-speak casts a shadow*** as if it were a cylinder as i put the sun behind a Gaussian function, resulting in a bent green function following the shape of the blue circle.

I now proceed to ***unwrap the shadow***. This gives me a new straight green function that differs from the original red one and would range from $[-\pi,\pi]$.

What is the formula for getting the shape of the unwrapped green function?

Desmos link involving my guess: https://www.desmos.com/3d/1b8ed83fc3

[image: Cast a shadow of a function onto a shape, then unwrap the shape]

*Additional more general question*: what if my blue curve is a different equation, for example $x^4+y^4=1$ instead of a perfect circle?

Comment: hint: use asp transformation for trigonometry

Comment: @Mathslover What's "asp" transformation? I'm searching for asp and I'm getting asp.net, which is something totally different.